# How can I get all html content including fixed content to move up at the end of browser scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I have an application which uses a background image via a 100vw and 100vh positioned: fixed div behind (containing the image as cover).

```
<app>
  <main>
     <!-- inline content - footer is inside here also -->
  </main>
</app>

<div id="background">
  <!-- has background image and is positioned: fixed, 100vh, 100vw -->
</div>
```

There is a footer that blends 0 to 1 opacity white which I want to blend with the white html's white background **when the user scrolls bottom.**

Problem at bottom scroll:
[image: https://imgur.com/Wa9SFrH]

Effect I want to achieve:
[image]

(Note: The positioned fixed div works well on chrome, it's safari that decides to leave the div and move all inline content as shown in problem).

I have already tried to change the div from positioned fixed to positioned absolute when the user reaches the bottom of scroll.

```
if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - 15)) { // -15 helped reduced FOUC but didn't stop it completely
  // set div to position absolute
} else {
  // set div to position fixed
}
```

The above code does achieve the effect I want but it causes a FOUC before the scroll event can execute the style changes resulting in a split second of the app seeming laggy. (I need the app to be completely fluid).

I've also considered adding an :after positioned below the footer with 100vh being fully white, but I don't know how to stop the browser from scrolling. (I want it to have the same pullback scrolling effect the safari browser gives when the user reaches bottom rather than halting the scroll completely)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

### Update

Created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f19dfwq9/2/) for this. You need to view it on Safari to see the problem.